# Peripheral definition

Tags: c

Could someone please explain the following construction to a beginner:

```
typedef struct
{
  __IO uint32_t CTRL;     /**< Control Register               */
  __IO uint32_t CNT;      /**< Counter Value Register         */
  __IO uint32_t COMP0;    /**< Compare Value Register 0       */
  __IO uint32_t COMP1;    /**< Compare Value Register 1       */
  __I uint32_t  IF;       /**< Interrupt Flag Register        */
  __IO uint32_t IFS;      /**< Interrupt Flag Set Register    */
  __IO uint32_t IFC;      /**< Interrupt Flag Clear Register  */
  __IO uint32_t IEN;      /**< Interrupt Enable Register      */
  __IO uint32_t FREEZE;   /**< Freeze Register                */
  __I uint32_t  SYNCBUSY; /**< Synchronization Busy Register  */
} RTC_TypeDef;    


#define RTC_BASE     (0x40080000UL)
#define RTC          ((RTC_TypeDef *) RTC_BASE)
```

especially the last line

Why are the brackets so unusual? What does the * mean? Pointer or multiply operator ?

Thanks

Comment: Pointer. It's all about pointers here. :-)

Comment: That struct is buggy. Since this is obviously a register map (for a RTC), it needs to be fixed into `((volatile RTC_TypeDef *) RTC_BASE)`, otherwise all code using it may contain random bugs. Also it is pretty confusing to use pointer arithmetic here, as there is no reason to. It is better to use `(*(volatile RTC_TypeDef *) RTC_BASE)` so that the code using that struct will be less confusing.

Comment: What "pointer arithmetic" @Lundin? RTC is defined as a pointer to struct, so it can be dereferenced in code like `RTC->CTRL = 1; RTC->IFS=2;` etc. Makes sense to me.

Comment: @GrahamS It wasn't really clear by my comment, but I wanted to prevent ugly things like `RTC[3] = ...` by not treating RTC as a pointer. And yes, there are people writing such code with "magic numbers" when they are writing hardware peripheral drivers. (I'm currently working with maintenance of such a program.) Anyway, the most important thing here is volatile: without it the code might crash & burn.

Answer (score 0):

> Why are the brackets so unusual? What does the * mean? Pointer or
>   multiply operator ?

`*` here is a pointer not multiplication operator.

There is nothing unusual here about the macro. It is just type casting the address to be of type `struct RTC_TypeDef`

Answer (score 0):

The structure definition is pretty straight forward, variables are encapsulated in a structure. That structure can then be referenced as `RTC_TypeDef` because you use `typedef`.

```
typedef struct
{
  __IO uint32_t CTRL;     /**< Control Register  */

  __IO uint32_t CNT;      /**< Counter Value Register  */
  __IO uint32_t COMP0;    /**< Compare Value Register 0  */
  __IO uint32_t COMP1;    /**< Compare Value Register 1  */
  __I uint32_t  IF;       /**< Interrupt Flag Register  */
  __IO uint32_t IFS;      /**< Interrupt Flag Set Register  */
  __IO uint32_t IFC;      /**< Interrupt Flag Clear Register  */
  __IO uint32_t IEN;      /**< Interrupt Enable Register  */

  __IO uint32_t FREEZE;   /**< Freeze Register  */
  __I uint32_t  SYNCBUSY; /**< Synchronization Busy Register  */
} RTC_TypeDef;            /** @} */
```

The following line means every time you write `RTC_BASE`, the compiler will replace that line with `(0x40080000UL)`

```
#define RTC_BASE          (0x40080000UL)
```

And finally, the following line can be broken into two parts:

```
(RTB_TypeDef *)RTC_BASE
```

Which means `(RTB_TypeDef *)(0x40080000UL)` - basically tells the compiler to treat memory address `0x40080000UL` as a pointer to `RTB_TypeDef`

and the extra parenthesis are there to denote a single variable as a compund expression RTC.
From that point on, whenever the compiler sees `RTC`, it will replace it with `(RTB_TypeDef *)(0x40080000UL)`, basically a convenient way to mark the beginning of this structure in memory

Comment: *... The following line means every time you write RTC_BASE, the compiler will replace that line with (0x40080000UL)*. Wrong, not the entire line, but just the `RTC_BASE`.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you will encounter a single or multiple `*` after a datatype (even a user defined datatype), its a pointer.

What you are calling a constructions:

```
typedef struct
{
    __IO uint32_t CTRL;     /**< Control Register  */

    __IO uint32_t CNT;      /**< Counter Value Register  */
    __IO uint32_t COMP0;    /**< Compare Value Register 0  */
    __IO uint32_t COMP1;    /**< Compare Value Register 1  */
    __I uint32_t  IF;       /**< Interrupt Flag Register  */
    __IO uint32_t IFS;      /**< Interrupt Flag Set Register  */
    __IO uint32_t IFC;      /**< Interrupt Flag Clear Register  */
    __IO uint32_t IEN;      /**< Interrupt Enable Register  */

    __IO uint32_t FREEZE;   /**< Freeze Register  */
    __I uint32_t  SYNCBUSY; /**< Synchronization Busy Register  */
} RTC_TypeDef;
```

is a structure and programmatically called a `struct`, a user-defined datatype. `struct` is keyword in C. And so is `typedef`. To keep it simple as of now, I'll say, `typedef` here is specifically used to have the convenience to write `RTC_TypeDef;` instead of having the need to write `struct stRTC` for example.

`RTC_BASE` is a macro. So, before compilation pre-processor will replace `RTC_BASE` with the value `(0x40080000UL)`, again, it is for convenience and readability.

This last line:

```
#define RTC          ((RTC_TypeDef *) RTC_BASE)
```

also is a macro defined. Which is nothing but a pointer of the `RTC_Typedef` type, pointing to whatever is located at the address `(0x40080000UL)`
So, before the compilation the pre-processor will replace all instances of `RTC` with `((RTC_TypeDef *)0x40080000UL)`. 
If you increment `RTC` pointer, it will increment by `sizeof(RTC_Typedef)`.